# Transpose columns of a table imported from mySQL

Tags: mysql, matlab

I used `struct2table(select(...))` to import data from mySQL.
Unfortunately the data is stored like this:

```
       A                  B
______________      ______________
[1x500 double]      [1x500 dobule]
```

I want to transpose the table entries so it looks like this:

```
       A                  B       
______________      ______________
[500x1 double]      [500x1 double]
```

I need to change it because I want to add `RowNames` and it does only work when the entries are transposed.

I could use `transpose()` but I have to do this a lot of times and I'm looking for something that takes the whole table as input and transposes it in the desired way.

I tried `flip()`, `rot90()`, `table'` but neither worked.

Maybe there is a way to avoid this problem during import but I don't know how. Tips on either are highly appreciated.

A 1x5 sample looks like this:

```
                  area
______________________________________________
6.8452    5.3581    3.2842   60.0434   15.5756    
(Columns 1 through 5)

                            inhabitants
_________________________________________________________________
11672        9136        5600      102379       26558       41437
(Columns 1 through 5)
```

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe; the OP here wants to transpose the elements in the table, not the whole table

Comment: can you show a sample data with small size, like `1x5` Im not sure what is the format you have or need. Is the data store like an array in one field column?

Comment: Yes I want to transpose only the elements, not the whole table

Answer (score 1):

Why not loop?

```
newTable = table();
for ii = 1:size(oldTable,2)
     newTable{:,ii} = oldTable{:,ii}.'; end

newTable.Properties.VariableNames = oldTable.Properties.VariableNames;
```

but, as you already indicate, it's probably best to avoid this problem during import...somehow.

Comment: thanks, this definitety works and as long as there is no import based solution I will use it.